# Ajax function to validate on click of a button:

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

In my page i have a
dropdown
Panel1
Panel2
Button to Move Next
onclick of dropdown data in Panel1 is displayed. and Panel 2 displays previously selected data.

When there is nothing selected indropdown Panel1 is set to invisible.

Now i want if there is nothing selected in dropdown.onclick of button an alert message to be displayed
 'please select a data for panel1 and then move next'

earlier i had done this using javascript function with a custom validation function on Next button. but now i want to upgrade
it to Ajax.

Javascript Code:

```
   function Validate(sender, args)
    {
            if (document.getElementById("ctl00_rightContainer_ContentTable1_Panel1").style.display == 'none') {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
            else {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }

    }
```

But after trying ajax function i used visible property and with that i get an error in javascript saying object not found since on load Panel1 is invisible. i hav upgraded my rest functions to ajax but i dont knw hw shal i do this.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal i hav edited my question plz hav a look

Answer (score 0):

If By AJAX you means Asp.net Update Panel then it is preet easy but i dont like it.

Put the Panel inside UpdatePanels

Dont forgot to add ScriptManager on top:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="sc1"/>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And for the dropdowns set AutoPostBack to true.

The dropdown will have a selectedIndex and in selectedindex check validations and show next panel or message

You can show message like this:

In Label

OR

Alert or some jQuery Popup

ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript(this.Page , typeof(Page) , "alertV" , "alert('Errors');" , true);

Answer (score 0):

If you set `Visible` property of server control to `false` it won't render at all and you can't show it from client-side code. Try to set `style="display:none;"` instead. This way panel will be rendered but not displayed on a page and you can show it from JavaScript.